# I am using react native webrtc but i am getting error of Could not add sender

Tags: react-native

// I am getting error of "Could not add sender" after using the getTracks and can i use ontrack and onicecandidate in react native webrtc.

```
const createOffer = async () => {
        try {
          peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(server);
          myremotevideo = new MediaStream();
    
          localstream.getTracks().map(tracks => {
            peerConnection.addTrack(tracks, localstream);
            tracks.stop()
          });
          
    
          // peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
          //   event.stram[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
          //     myremotevideo.addTrack(track);
          //   });
          // };
    
          // peerConnection.onicecandidate = async event => {
          //   if (event.candidate) {
          //     console.log('candiatemay', event.candidate);
          //   }
          // };
    
          const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    
          await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    
          console.log('myoffer', offer);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('err', error);
        }
      };
```